# mapping is bijective if $\lambda=? $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> We consider the mapping $f$ from $\mathbb{C}$ in itself defined by~: 
>   $$ f:z\longmapsto Z=f(z)=\dfrac{z+i\lambda \bar{z}}{1+i\lambda}$$
>   with $\bar{z}$ is the conjugates of $z$ and $\lambda > 0$
>
> 1. The mapping $f$ is bijective if $\lambda$ is

- A) null
- B) equal $1$
- C) different of $1$
- D) different of $-1$

indeed,

$f$ is bijective iff:
$$\forall Z\in\mathcal{C},\quad \exists ! z\in\mathcal{C}\quad \text{ such that } : f(z)=Z \Longleftrightarrow  z=f^{-1}(Z)$$

we looking for $z$  in $\mathbb{C}$  such that  $z=f^{-1}(Z)$
so we have to find  $z$ in function of  $Z$

we've

$$
\begin{align*}
f(z)&=Z \\
\dfrac{z+i\lambda \bar{z}}{1+i\lambda}&=Z\\
(z+i\lambda \bar{z})&=Z(1+i\lambda )\\
(1-i\lambda )(z+i\lambda \bar{z})&=Z(1+\lambda^{2})\\
(1-i\lambda )z+i\lambda(1-i\lambda ) \bar{z}&=Z(1+\lambda^{2})
\end{align*}$$

- am i right
- Someone could complete my proof without using $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

i added my new attempts

$$\begin{align}
(z+i\lambda \bar{z})&=Z(1+i\lambda )\quad (E:1)\\
(\bar{z}-i\lambda z)&=\bar{Z}(1-i\lambda )\quad (E:2)\\
\\
(E:1) \iff i\lambda \bar{z}&=Z(1+i\lambda )-z\\
(E:2) \iff i\lambda \bar{z}&=i\lambda \bar{Z}(1-i\lambda )-\lambda^{2} z    \\
(E:1)+(E:2) \iff Z(1+i\lambda )-z&=i\lambda \bar{Z}(1-i\lambda )-\lambda^{2} z\\
(1-\lambda^{2})z&=(1+i\lambda Z)-i\lambda (1-i\lambda )\bar{Z}\\
f \textrm{ is bijective } \iff \lambda^{2} &\neq  1\\
\textrm{since } \lambda > 0 \textrm{ then }& \lambda \neq 1\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: write $z=a+b i, Z=c+d i$, you then get a linear equation with unknowns a,b.

Comment: Can several answers be true? Because if only one answer is supposed to be true then $\lambda = 0$ is the obvious choice!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net don't forget by hypothese we 've $\lambda > 0$

Answer (score 5):

Since $1+i\lambda\neq 0$, $f$ is bijective iff $g(z)=z+i\lambda\bar z$ is bijective. Let $z=x+iy$. Then,
$$g(x+iy)=(x+\lambda y)+i(y+\lambda x)$$
To see if $g$ is bijective we can work in the vector space $\Bbb R^2$ instead of $\Bbb C$. Now $g$ is a linear application and its matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&\lambda\\\lambda&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, $g$ is bijective iff $1-\lambda^2\neq0$. Since $\lambda>0$, $g$ is bijective iff $\lambda\neq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+yi$. Then

$$\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{z+i\lambda \bar{z}}{1+i\lambda} \\
 &= \frac{x+yi+i\lambda(x-yi)}{1+i\lambda} \\
 &= \frac 1{1+i\lambda}[(1+i\lambda)x+(i-i\lambda)y]
\end{align}$$

Note that if $\lambda=1$ then $y$ drops out of the expression and the function cannot possibly be a bijection. It is pretty easy to see that if $\lambda\ne \pm1$ then the coefficients in $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent.

So the answer is C) Different from $1$.